# convert 720p to 1080p 60fps ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, convert, video-player, mencoder

I'm confused where to ask. I want to ask, please give the encode script to convert the video I made from 720p to 1080 60fps. when I check the video I can't reach 60fps if I use the script below

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1920:-2 \
       -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 \
       -c:a copy \
       output.mp4
```

Please help me. i am using ffmpeg in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I don't think the quality will improve, if you convert from from 720p to 1080p, because you cannot improve the real resolution above that of the original version.

Comment: @sudodus is there any solution ? I see in Adobe Premiere Video can be 60fps

Comment: What is the frame rate of the original video file?

Comment: @sudodus 24 fps

Comment: I don't think the quality will improve, if you convert from from 24 fps to 60 fps, because you cannot improve the real [time] resolution above that of the original version. Some software (video player) may play better, if the conversion creates better interpolated values than what the video player can do. -- What happens if you stay with 720 p and try to convert to 60 fps?

Comment: I think if using 60fps the video will be smoother and no one will split the video. so I want to convert to fix that.

Comment: I suggest that you try to convert only the frame rate, not the geometrial resolution (stay with 720p).

Comment: how? I ask for an example script for ffmpeg

Comment: If you simply change the fps from 24 to 60fps, the video will play more than twice as fast as ffmpeg will not add extra frames ... you cannot make the video smoother this way. But you might use something like [slomovideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/) to add extra (interpolated) frames and then [change the fps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462731/using-ffmpeg-to-change-framerate/45465730). But I don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: Regarding the upscaling from 720p to 1080p you could use some [machine learning algorithms](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/7wchqe/d_is_there_any_app_that_uses_ai_to_increase/) on every frame. Actually, I think you should just keep your 720p24 video as enhancing quality will take a long time and the results will be negligible.